# Set Default settings for all users in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

i haven't found a way to set the default settings for all our users on install for VSCode.

All i really need set automatically is the ' "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,' setting.
These are students i cant ask them to do it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.14, we do not support this scenario but we are tracking the features request here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27972

As a workaround, you can try using an extension such as [Fetch User Environment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michaelnewton.fetch-user-environment)